# How do I read the contents of a file as bytes?

Tags: python, file-io, numpy-ndarray

I have this file which is encrypted using AES. What I am trying to do is read this file and store the bytes as an array. I am getting this error which can be expected. I wrote the array which had encrypted bytes to this file. I want to store `fe` at a location, `fa` at another and so on.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

```
with open(ENCRYPTED_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        byte_array = np.fromiter(file.read(), dtype='c').view(np.uint8)
        total_bytes = len(byte_array)
```

[image: This is encrypted text file.]

Comment: Why are you trying to open the file in *text* mode? Just open it in binary mode and use `np.frombuffer` not `np.fromiter`

Comment: I literally tried opening it in binary mode before. It just didn't work. And now it works. Could it tell how is ``np.frombuffer`` different than ``np.fromiter``. Anyway, Thanks  you very much.

Comment: with open(ENCRYPTED_FILE, 'rb') ? is it for bytes read ?

Comment: @pippo1980 No. rb for reading in binary mode.

Comment: @FrankShrestha ouch !!!